# Bootstrap button group mobile formatting reset

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile

I am using bootstrap button groups for formatting on my desktop display of my webpage for groups of check boxes and radio buttons.  However, when the button group is displayed on a mobile device it doesn’t look correct.  I am wondering if there is an easy way of removing these formats to display standard check boxes and radio buttons.  Thank you for your help.

```
<div class="container">

<div class="col-md-6">
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label id="label1" class="btn btn-default">
        <input type="checkbox" name="popcorn" value="popcorn">Popcorn</input>
    </label>
    <label id="label2" class="btn btn-default">
        <input type="checkbox" name="pictures" value="pictures">Pictures</input>
    </label>
    <label id="label3" class="btn btn-default">
        <input type="checkbox" name="events" value="events">Events</input>
    </label>
</div>    </div></div></div>
```

UPDATE:
I guess I should add that it's wrapped in columns. The display-inline suggestion had no effect

Comment: whats the problem? what happen on mobile show the code or image.

Comment: The button group goes onto the next line - it doesn't all stay grouped together

Comment: add css `display:inline`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this?

https://jsfiddle.net/dalinhuang/31gz6dh4/4/

```
.btn {
  float: none;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.btn-group {
  display: flex;
}
```

or you want overflow:

https://jsfiddle.net/dalinhuang/31gz6dh4/2/

or in the center:

https://jsfiddle.net/dalinhuang/31gz6dh4/3/

Comment: The display: flex was the part i was looking for, however, on desktop viewing, it removes the center property I also have applied. Is there anyway to apply it only on small  and xs sizes